# Deducing type of initializer list by first element

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, list-initialization

Is the following code correct according to the Standard (note that type deduced by first element in the list is applied to the second list-initialized element)?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <initializer_list>

struct A {};

int main()
{
    auto l = {A{}, {}};
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::initializer_list<A>, decltype(l)>, "!");
}
```

Recently, I wanted to utilize `std::initializer_list` as continuous storage for Vulkan structures:

```
auto dependencies = {
    vk::SubpassDependency{
        VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,
        0,
        vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eBottomOfPipe,
        vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput,
        vk::AccessFlagBits::eMemoryRead,
        vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentRead | vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentWrite,
        vk::DependencyFlagBits::eByRegion
    },
    {
        0,
        VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,
        vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput,
        vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eBottomOfPipe,
        vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentRead | vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentWrite,
        vk::AccessFlagBits::eMemoryRead,
        vk::DependencyFlagBits::eByRegion
    }
};
```

And found out that the above syntax works. The syntax is more terse then writing `std::initializer_list<vk::SubpassDependency>` instead of `auto`, but compiler is *GCC* (`set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)`) and I don't know is it GCC specific extension/oversight or standard core language feature.

Previously I thought I have to specify types of all the elements during list initialization in explicit manner to get valid initializer for `std::initializer_list` via `auto x = {<list>};` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is standard to my reading. The key here is in the deduction process

> **[temp.deduct.call]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.call#1) If removing references and cv-qualifiers from P gives
>   `std​::​initializer_­list<P'>` or `P'[N]` for some P' and N and the
>   argument is a non-empty initializer list ([dcl.init.list]), then
>   deduction is performed instead for each element of the initializer
>   list, taking P' as a function template parameter type and the
>   initializer element as its argument,

Each element of the initializer list is taken as an argument to deduce the element type from. For the first one, deduction succeeds. Whereas the others are non-deduced contexts

> **[temp.deduct.type]**
>
> [5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.type#5) The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> - A function parameter for which the associated argument is an initializer list ([dcl.init.list]) but the parameter does not have a
>     type for which deduction from an initializer list is specified
>     ([temp.deduct.call]). [ Example:
>
>   ```
>   template<class T> void g(T);
>   g({1,2,3});                 // error: no argument deduced for T
>   ```
>
>   — end example ]

For template argument deduction to succeed, a template parameter must agree in its deduction from different arguments, so long as deduction is possible from an argument. If there is a consensus (even of just one) deduction succeeds.

> **[temp.deduct.type]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.type#2) In some cases, the deduction is done using a single set of
>   types P and A, in other cases, there will be a set of corresponding
>   types P and A. Type deduction is done independently for each P/A pair,
>   and the deduced template argument values are then combined. If type
>   deduction cannot be done for any P/A pair, or if for any pair the
>   deduction leads to more than one possible set of deduced values, or if
>   different pairs yield different deduced values, or if any template
>   argument remains neither deduced nor explicitly specified, template
>   argument deduction fails. The type of a type parameter is only deduced
>   from an array bound if it is not otherwise deduced.

By virtue of being non-deduced contexts, the trailing elements can't disagree with the deduction done from the first element. So template argument deduction should be successful. Then, with the type correctly deduced, initialization can proceed for each element of the `std::initializer_list` from its corresponding initializer.

Comment: Your last quote has *If type deduction cannot be done for any P/A pair, or if for any pair the deduction leads to more than one possible set of deduced values, or if different pairs yield different deduced values, or if any template argument remains neither deduced nor explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.*.  Doesn't that mean the non-deduced parameter does stop the deduction process?

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica - Cannot be done for **any pair** should be read as all pairs failing. Could be better worded, I suppose.

Comment: That's not how English works IMHO.  It really should be reworded if that is what they want.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica - English doesn't have a use for "any" to mean "all"? I'm fairly certain it does, but I'm willing to be corrected on this.

Comment: It does, but it depends on the context.  In *Any child would know that.* it means no matter which child you pick. they would know. To me the use of *any* in *cannot be done for any P/A pair* is the one of use, not every use.  I'm going to refrain from voting though and let other decide.  Personally I think the code is ill-formed, but not enough to make that an answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica - If this code should be ill-formed then I guess so should this use-case of [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity). I am still far more inclined to believe this is a wording issue with a clear intent.

Comment: Alright, I'll go with it's just the wording that's confusing me.  Now that you've pointed it out, I can't believe I forgot about that technique.  Have a +1

Comment: Should I clean up the comments or do you want to leave them in case others have the same issue?

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica - I think the discussion has merit. So I say let's leave them.

Answer (score 2):

I think that, yes, this code is "correct" in the sense that this is supposed to compile and `dependencies` is guaranteed to be an `std::initializer_list<vk::SubpassDependency>`. The type of `dependencies` will be deduced from your top-level *braced-init-list* via template argument deduction for a parameter of type `std::initializer_list<U>` where `U` is an invented template parameter [[dcl.type.auto.deduct]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec.auto#dcl.type.auto.deduct-4). Your top-level *braced-init-list* has one element from which `U` can be deduced to `vk::SubpassDependency` [[temp.deduct.call]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.call#1). There are no other elements of that *braced-init-list* from which a conflicting deduction could be made. Thus, the type of `dependencies` will be deduced to `std::initializer_list<vk::SubpassDependency>`.

Initializing elements of type `vk::SubpassDependency` from the remaining *braced-init-list*s during construction of the initializer list object does not involve a narrowing conversion [[dcl.init.list]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#7), so this should be well-formed.

Despite this being well-formed, I woud argue that readability of this approach is not great. Since no explicit type is given for `dependencies` and only one lone element of the *braced-init-list* has a type at all, one is almost forced to wonder whether this actually does what one thinks it probably does. If code that's supposed to do something as simple as initializing an array of things requires consulting a language lawyer to figure out whether that's really actually what it does, then that code should probably not be written that way. Why not simply write

```cpp
vk::SubpassDependency dependencies[] = {
    {
        VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,
        0,
        vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eBottomOfPipe,
        vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput,
        vk::AccessFlagBits::eMemoryRead,
        vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentRead | vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentWrite,
        vk::DependencyFlagBits::eByRegion
    },
    {
        0,
        VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,
        vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput,
        vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eBottomOfPipe,
        vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentRead | vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentWrite,
        vk::AccessFlagBits::eMemoryRead,
        vk::DependencyFlagBits::eByRegion
    }
};
```

This essentially does the exact same thing [[dcl.init.list]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#5), just that everyone should immediately understand what's going on here…

Comment: I like this note about readability. Really I get on `auto`/`std::initializer_list` because of `std::initializer_list::size()`, but there is `std::size()` free function in modern C++ applicable to arrays.

Comment: @TomilovAnatoliy yes, arrays can be used in essentially the same ways as `std::initializer_list`, just that you have to pass around begin/end manually (`std::span`/`array_view` will hopefully fix that soon, until then you can just use the [GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL) equivalents). Personally, I would just avoid `std::initializer_list` except for its original purpose of enabling initializing container types with a set of elements. There is a lot of magic behavior associated with `std::initializer_list` in the language…

Comment: One advantage of `std::initializer_list` is its inherent immutability.

Comment: @TomilovAnatoliy if you make an array of `const` elements, you get the exact same thing. Per [\[dcl.init.list\]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#5) `std::initializer_list` is literally defined to be equivalent to an array of `const` elements… ;)

Comment: I know, but I have to type `const` in case of array ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the C++{ 17 Standard (8.2.3 Explicit type conversion (functional notation)

> 1 A simple-type-speciﬁer (10.1.7.2) or typename-speciﬁer (17.6)
>   followed by a parenthesized optional expression list or by a
>   braced-init-list (the initializer) constructs a value of the speciﬁed
>   type given the initializer. If the type is a placeholder for a deduced
>   class type, it is replaced by the return type of the function selected
>   by overload resolution for class template deduction (16.3.1.8) for the
>   remainder of this section.

So this

```
vk::SubpassDependency{
    VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,
    0,
    vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eBottomOfPipe,
    vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput,
    vk::AccessFlagBits::eMemoryRead,
    vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentRead | vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentWrite,
    vk::DependencyFlagBits::eByRegion
}
```

is an expression with an  explicit casting.